# 外付けGPU(eGPU)から出力できないディスプレイの解決方法

Tags: gpu

以下のような環境で作業をしております。
外付けGPUに接続しているディスプレイを変更したら、出力できなくなりました。
切り分け確認をしましたが、なにが原因かわからずにおります。。
具体的な方法をご存知の方がいれば、助言いただきたいです！

---

本体：mac mini(2018)
外付けGPU：Razer Code XにRadeon RX580搭載
ディスプレイ1：PHILIPS製1080p
ディスプレイ2：DMM.make製4K
ディスプレイ3,4：PHILIPS製1080p
・Mac miniとeGPUは付属のthunderboltで接続
・Mac miniとディスプレイ1をHDMIで接続->使用可○
＜変更前＞
・eGPUとディスプレイ3,4をHDMIでデュアル接続->使用可○
＜変更後＞
・eGPUとディスプレイ2をHDMIで接続->使用不可×
●eGPUはMacが推奨している組み合わせのものです。
●eGPUは4K出力に対応しています。

---

＜確認したこと＞
・Mac miniとディスプレイ2をHDMIで接続->使用可○
・eGPUとディスプレイ1をHDMIで接続->使用可○
・ディスプレイ2のHDMIケーブルのポートを変更->使用不可×

Comment: 「ディスプレイ2のHDMIケーブルのポートを変更->使用不可×」というのは、ディスプレイ２の複数あるHDMI端子のうち、eGPUと接続して表示が出る端子と、表示が出ない端子があるという事ですか？
使っているeGPUの型番などの詳細を質問に追加すると、回答が得られるかもしれません。（世の中のeGPUがすべて同じ機能や性能を持っている訳ではないですから）

Comment: コメントありがとうございます！
ディスプレイ2には3つのHDMI入力ポートがありますが、3つともeGPUを認識しない状態です。
eGPUは、記載の通り「Razer Code XにRadeon RX580」です。

HDMI1.4でもHDMI2.0でも同様に、認識できません。。